# jQuery Plugin 2 Instances does not run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, namespaces, timeout

I have built a jQuery Plugin that uses `setTimeout` and is saved ageist the selectors `.data()` but for some reason the timeouts seem to run independently as both timeouts are affecting the same element can some one spot what i have done wrong and i'm sorry the size of this jsFiddle is huge as the Plugin supports alot,

Modes - Horizontal / Vertical
Direction - locked so if on Horizontal only left or right and same for vertical with up and down

This is the code loading 2 at once,
http://jsfiddle.net/barkermn01/NRPMk/7/

this is the code loading 1 at once,
http://jsfiddle.net/barkermn01/NRPMk/8/

Could some one please explain how this is happening and what i can do to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
sorry the setTimeout on more than one only fires the once

**UPDATE: AGAIN**
fixed the `setTimeout` not firing a second time forgot to tell the plugin it was running

Just a Note as to the Comment this problem is not fixed the only thing i have fixed is the first update i have not fixed the 2 instance problem where the timeout is only working on the last instance of the plugin

Comment: If your question has been answered you can either delete this question since you no longer need help or add the solution you came up with as an official answer then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The problem is not fixed, I have fixed the first update I added saying the timeout was not running past the first run, i'm still having the 2 or more instances breaking the instances apart from the last one

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly. What's not working exactly? Your fiddles seem to work for me in Chrome.

Comment: only the bottom one is working the first one is not animating every 5 seconds? or that is what is happening for me in chrome and Firefox just tested that now